# PHP SOAP Request for 3PL Central

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

Can anyone guide me how to make a PHP SOAP request using 3PL Central API?

I have 3PL KEY, Login, Password, and Facility ID. The files given by the client are WSDL file, a XML Request file, a XML Response file, and a C# example, which is not helping in anyway.

I am new to SOAP... so, I guess... a link to a good tutorial about PHP and SOAP would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bundle of thanx goes to "jacobdubail."

Check this link for solution: http://forum.foxycart.com/discussion/5370/help-transforming-datafeed-for-3rd-party-integration/p1

It helped me alot.

Answer (score 0):

you may do by http request using curl call. I have done using this to make drupal module. They have great help for developers. you may look there. https://developer.3plcentral.com/#6d6ce87a-4aed-48db-9609-c1b47f51378e

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35029955)